# Enable ascending and descending sorting of numbers that are of the keyword type (Elasticsearch)

Tags: javascript, sorting, elasticsearch, dataprovider

My task is to sort documents in ascending and descending order, but 'number' must remain of the keyword type. I read other posts on a similar topic, and tried to add an 'number' of type integer, but I didn't succeed and the index crashes. I am attaching the current configuration in the esMapping.js file.

Is there a way to fix this esMapping.js file so that ascending and descending sorting works?

```
"settings": {
    "analysis": {
        "analyzer": {
            "document_number_analyzer": {
                "type": "custom",
                "tokenizer": "document_number_tokenizer"
            }
        },
        "tokenizer": {
            "document_number_tokenizer": {
                "type": "pattern",
                "pattern": "-0*([1-9][0-9]*)\/",
                "group": 1
            }
        },
    }
}
```

Mapping:

```
"number": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "copy_to": [
                "_summary"
            ],
            "fields": {
                "sequenceNumber": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "analyzer": "document_number_analyzer"
                }
            }
        }
```

**EDIT:**

Error after using integer sub-field to sort documents:

```
022-05-18 11:33:32.5830 [ERROR] ESIndexerLogger Failed to commit bulk. Errors:
index returned 400 _index: adama_gen_ro_importdocument _type: _doc _id: 4c616067-4beb-4484-83cc-7eb9d36eb175 _version: 0 error: Type: mapper_parsing_exception Reason: "failed to parse field [number.sequenceNumber] of type [integer] in document with id '4c616067-4beb-4484-83cc-7eb9d36eb175'. Preview of field's value: 'BS-000011/2022'" CausedBy: "Type: number_format_exception Reason: "For input string: "BS-000011/2022"""
```

Comment: You should simply add an integer sub-field and sort by that field

Comment: Hi @Val. How to reach it (if I can get a little help-suggestion)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mapping needs to be like this:

```
    "number": {
        "type": "keyword",
        "copy_to": [
            "_summary"
        ],
        "fields": {
            "sequenceNumber": {
                "type": "integer"
            }
        }
    }
```

And then you can simply sort by `number.sequenceNumber`

Comment: I did so and ran the reindex, but the sequenceNumber is not written to the index.

Comment: it is but it's not a field that you'll see in your source document, try sorting on`number.sequenceNumber`, you'll see

Comment: Hi @Val. Sorting documents works using the integer sub-field, but I will have to make a change due to an error I attached to the task. do you have any idea? If I'm not mistaken, the problem is comparing two different data types.

Comment: Can you create a new question explaining your new issue?

Comment: Hi @Val. I asked a new question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72338536/failed-to-parse-field-of-type-integer?noredirect=1#comment127796479_72338536